# flash AS3 e4x - getting hold of child nodes

Tags: actionscript-3, e4x

I am aware that you can use syntax such as:

```
xml..Group
```

And this is supposed to return an XMLList of Groups anywhere in the xml. This works fine if I have more than one , but fails if there is only one .

Am I wrong in my assumption that it should return one? I trace xml..Group.length() and it is 0, but the Group is definately in the xml.

Any ideas on how you can get one or more Group nodes from my xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake in my xml, there is no problems using this method on one or more items.

Answer (score 0):

I think we will need a bit of code and/or of your XML to undersyand what is going on :)

Comment: Thanks, I would have posted some code, it was my error, you can target one or more using parent..node without issues.

Thanks for replying..